# Can't deploy extension (firefox)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am closely following the tutorial [here](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-4/) as I attempt to create a Firefox extension. I have the following tree for my extension:

```
backtosearch
  +-chrome
    +-content
      backtosearch.xul
  +-chrome.manifest
  +-install.rdf
```

I have created a testing profile for FF called "Extension Testing" and have added a file to the profile extensions folder "backtosearch@my.name" containing absolute path to the extension folder. I have reloaded the browser chrome using the extension development extension and restarted the browser - but I see no new button.

I have simplified the tutorial (as I only require one button), and my .xul contains only that. My chrome.manifest file contains:

```
content backtosearch chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://backtosearch/content/backtosearch.xul
```

The  extension is not showing under view -> toolbars or tools -> addons

Thanks for any help

**install.rdf**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">

        <!-- Required Items -->
        <em:id>backtosearch@dylan.lloyd</em:id>
        <em:name>Back To Search</em:name>
        <em:version>1.0</em:version>

        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>3.5.*</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Optional Items -->
        <em:creator>Dylan Lloyd</em:creator>
        <em:description>Adds options to return to your last search immediately.</em:description>
        <em:homepageURL>http://www.getyourkeywords.com/</em:homepageURL>

    </Description>
</RDF>
```

**backtosearch@dylan.lloyd**

```
C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\backtosearch\
```

Comment: Is the extension showing up in Tools->Add-ons?

Comment: interestingly, i tried uninstalling the "tuttoolbar", placing the files on my desktop and creating a "pointer" file to it like i had been for mine. it didn't work either.

Comment: If you can't this sorted with the help already provided, zip the files into an xpi file, upload it somewhere and we'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I found out in moziila own documentation the mistake on this hello world.

You can read on:
https://github.com/oschrenk/firefox-extension

```
I had written

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-RDF-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-RDF#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">

as the root element, but it needs to be all lowercase

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
```

Just update the install.rdf =)

Comment: This is the correct answer. If this comment gets read by the post author, please approve it as correct so it moves to the top.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it's not clear what the problem is. The most likely cause, as sdwilsh noted is that the Extension didn't get registered. If this is the case, the extension will not appear in Tools -> Addons.

You can try to set [extensions.logging.enable pref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences) to true to help debugging. Maybe try installing a [helloworld extension](http://mozilla.doslash.org/stuff/helloworld.zip) first?

Possible causes:

- You didn't use the correct name for the "link" file (must match the extension ID).
- The "link" file contents is invalid (the path format is OS-native). In your case the path should end with "backtosearch"
- Incorrect install.rdf. You can check it at least to be valid XML by opening it in Firefox (possibly renaming to .xml first) -- if the yellow screen opens, its invalid.
- Installed in the wrong profile or didn't really restart Firefox.

If the extension is registered, try opening `chrome://backtosearch/content/backtosearch.xul` in Firefox (by copying that to the Location bar) -- if any errors appear, you should fix them. If the file loads successfully (may be empty), there's a problem with your overlay's contents, which is hard to debug without seeing it. Perhaps start with an overlay that's known to work?

Comment: thank you for your response, it's greatly appreciated. I am sure of the link, path, and path format. I will enable the logging and check the xml validity. I have reloaded the chrome, closed and restarted firefox, and restarted the computer, and triple checked that I placed the link file in the correct directory. (one scare that crossed my mind, originally the alt profile was called "ExtensionTesting", and was later modified to "Extension Testing", while its profile directory name did not change. could that mean anything? but other extensions i installed into the profile showed up there)

Comment: after checking: install.rdf is valid xml.

Comment: attempting to open the path gave me a blank page, and wouldnt really "register" my [enter] presses or "go" clicks. what could this mean? Also, I'm a bit confused about the "registering process", can you explain that a bit more? thaanks again so much.

Comment: So you didn't say if the extension was showing up in Tools -> Addons. If it's not, you have a problem in the "link" file or the extension's install.rdf. First try installing in a different profile and if it fails, post the exact paths to+contents of the link file and install.rdf // Re #3: empty page with no errors is OK as long as its title is the chrome:// URL, not "(Untitled)". "view source" on it should show your overlay's contents.

Comment: actually, it just refuses to go there. it was a blank tab because i opened a new tab. i posted the files you mentioned. thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Is it true that the extension does not appear in Tools -> Addons? If so, you messed up its registration. I successfully got it to appear in Tools -> Addons by using your install.rdf and your link file. So as I said before, try installing to a different profile, then post the exact **paths to** the link file (in the new profile) and install.rdf. Also did you try to enable logging?

Comment: i did enable logging, but I'm not sure where I view the logs? the path is C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5uybok14.ExtensionTesting\extensions, the path inside is C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\backtosearch\, and I have also tried moving it all to c:\test\, and I have also tried using an unzipped http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensionwiz/ generated ext., as well as a COMPLETELY c&p ext from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension, using sample@example.net. all to no success. I even tried all of this on a third brand new profile.

Comment: I'm sorry it's so frustrating for you, but it's definitely not common to have problems with this. My best guess right now is that your editor inserts the Unicode byte order mark into the beginning of the link file. It would appear as three junk bytes when you look at it in binary. You can send the link file to me: asqueella@gmail.com. I would prefer to continue over e-mail anyways, since the comments system here is ridiculous.

Comment: re logging - I just updated the developer.mozilla.org page to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through [Mozilla's Add-On Validation page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/validate).  It might just tell you what the error is.  If it is a javascript error, it will tell you for sure.

Now, I had the same problem - when I loaded my addon, my toolbar didn't appear, and even though the addon showed in "Tools > Addons", when I clicked on the "options" button, everything froze.

Turned out, there were several errors.

- The optionsurl in my install.rdf had "cchrome" instead of "chrome".
- In my main .js file, I forgot a ";" at the end of a line with a var
  assignment.
- In my xul file, I did not leave a space: `label="string"tooltip="string"` between the two property assignments.

  - I had a hanging `</toolbarbutton>` from where I copied one line to the next.  This is what **really** caused the problem.  In the code file, the line was very long, and I never saw that part!

The combination was total failure, even though it passed fine in the Mozilla Validator.
The Validator, in my opinion *should* have caught the cchrome thing. It *would* have caught the javascript error.

Anyway, I tell you that in case such might be YOUR problem.